# Не получается подключиться к бд postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных через intellij idea, test connection проходит нормально, но после появляется пустое подключение без базы данных и сущностей. Подскажите, что может быть?!
[image: Свойства подключения к бд]

[image: Сама база данных]

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в Settings -> Appearance and Behaivior -> password. Возможно у вас там отключено сохранение пароля.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA иногда очень глючит в плане подключения к базам данных. Решаю вопрос реконнектом и постоянным апдейтом. (Ctrl + F5).

Comment: Да как то не вариант. Собственно и не помогает.